# vue3-google-map with Nuxt

Tags: google-maps, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I've already used this `vue3-google-map` plugin in some Vue projects but now I'm working on a Nuxt project and I want to use this here as well. Is there any way to add it to Nuxt?

[Here is the documentation:](https://vue3-google-map.netlify.app/getting-started/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the vue3-google-map plugin in a Nuxt project.

1. Install the plugin with terminal:

   ```
   npm install vue3-google-map
   ```
2. Create a new file called *vue-google-maps.js* in the plugins directory of your Nuxt project.
3. In the *vue-google-maps.js* file, import the vue3-google-map plugin and add it to the Nuxt plugins array:

   ```
   import Vue from 'vue';
   import VueGoogleMaps from 'vue3-google-maps';

   Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
     load: {
       key: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
       libraries: 'places',
     },
   });
   ```
4. In your Nuxt configuration file (*nuxt.config.js*), add the *vue-google-maps.js* file to the *plugins* array:

   ```
   export default {
     // ...
     plugins: [
       // ...
       '@/plugins/vue-google-maps',
     ],
     // ...
   }
   ```
5. In your Vue component, you can now use the `<GmapMap>` component provided by the vue3-google-map plugin to display a Google Map.

Answer (score 5):

From what I can find, this library doesn't support use as a global 'plugin' within Nuxt 3.

Most of the working examples I could find, and the approach we're using in our project, do the following:

1. Install the plugin within your Nuxt app using whichever package manager you use.
2. Skip adding the plugin in `~/plugins/`
3. Import the map components within your components or templates using:

`import { GoogleMap, Marker, etc } from 'vue3-google-map'`

Note: *The approach suggested by Jakub, whilst being valid for many such dependencies, did not work for us with vue3-google-map. Jabub's answer is a working method for `fawmi/vue-google-maps` which has been tweaked slightly from [here](https://github.com/fawmi/vue-google-maps/issues/95#issuecomment-1177544048)*